# Run taskA and run next tasks with parameters, that returned taskA in luigi

Tags: python, pipeline, luigi

I have task, which generates which files should be processed:

```
class TaskA(luigi.Task):
    def run(self):
        # some code which generates list of files into output()
    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget(filepath='/path/to/process_these_files.json')
```

And I have wrapper task, which should run TaskA, get parameters, and run processing task with values, which I put into process_these_files.json

```
class RunAll(luigi.WrapperTask):
    def requires(self):
        files = json.load(TaskA().open('r'))
        for file in files:
            yield ProcessFileTask(file=file)
```

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use dynamic dependencies. These are dependencies that are know  at runtime. Each time you `yield` a dynamic dependency the `run()` method will hold until the dependency is  done.

For example:

```
class RunAll(luigi.WrapperTask): 
    def requires(self): 
        return TaskA() 

    def run(self):
        files = json.load(self.input().open('r')) 
        for file in files: 
            yield ProcessFileTask(file=file)
```

Also see https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html#dynamic-dependencies

Comment: I've already tried this method, but if I am using 2+ workers there are infinite  looping issues even if task from dynamic dependencies is done